# Subfolder Multisite : optional www subdomain

Tags: multisite

I have installed a WP Multisite using subfolders rather than subdomains.  At the time of installation I was on www.mydomain.com and created 2 blogs:

- www.mydomain.com/blog1
- www.example.com/blog2

If I navigate to my WP network without the www subdomain (http://example.com/blog1) I either get redirected to the site root (http://www.example.com) or I get a page/post not found message.

How can I make my multisite work with our without the www subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

I use the plugin "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" for mapping domains to subfoldered-subsites. Works well (even though it hasn't been updated in 2 years), once you closely follow the instructions.

Available here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ .

(Although, on retrospect, this may not entirely be the answer to the OP's question; I may have misunderstood his intent.)